# How do I reference a view (UIImageView) by it's Label property?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview

I've created a series of UIImageViews and I need to match each one to a string i get from a Dictionary.  I've decided the best way to do that is to match the Label property with the string. The label property has been set to match the name of the object.

How do i reference the UIImageView's label property in code?

Edit: Is there some easier way to match a string to an object?

Comment: What label property are you referring to?

Comment: In Interface builder under the Identity section there is a property "Label"  I can't find the property in the documentation, but I swear someone told me once that it was possible to refer to this "label" in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might make more sense to create a subclass of UIimageView that includes an NSString instance variable called "label" or whatever. Then you can easily set or reference the instances of your subclass like this: myCustomImageView.label.

Comment: I have the same issue as _hover_. But a label instance variable in a subclass wouldn't have the **label** value assigned in Interface Builder and it's only when defining these UIImageViews in Interface Builder that I know which one is which and can give them a unique **label**.  I have a bunch of UIImageView's in a collection and the only place I could find to uniquely identify them was with the **Label** field.  But like hover I can't find any way to get at the Label from within the UIImageView class.